# Why does the "availability" property point back to a page on schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I’m trying to use the `availability` property and I don’t understand why you would want to point it back to a page on schema.org like the following:

```
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>Available today
```

Answer (score 2):

Schema.org’s [`availability` property](http://schema.org/availability) expects a value of the type [`ItemAvailability`](http://schema.org/ItemAvailability).

`ItemAvailability` is an [`Enumeration`](http://schema.org/Enumeration) type which has several "enumeration members" that you can find on the bottom of the page ([`Discontinued`](http://schema.org/Discontinued), [`InStock`](http://schema.org/InStock) etc.).

Using such an enumeration member has the advantage that data consumers can "understand" your item availability, because these URIs have defined meanings. If everyone would use free text, it would be way harder (or even impossible) for data consumers to make use of this property.

Note that you don’t *have* to use these pre-defined enumeration members. You could even come up with your own set of URIs. See their blog post [Schema.org markup for external lists](http://blog.schema.org/2012/05/schemaorg-markup-for-external-lists.html).